# Is it possible to grant access to objects in a Google Cloud Storage bucket to non-Google adminstered email addresses?

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage

Wondering what options there are to add permissions for Storage Viewer access to a GCS bucket for non-Google administered email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#scopes), it is not possible. As shown, the grantee must have a google email address or a google groups email address.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to activate your non-google address at google using this form : https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail

After that, the address is known from Google and can be used in GCS

Answer (score 1):

You can now produce "signed URLs". Create a Service account, download its JSON key file, give it object Reader permissions and generate the signed URL -- it's a long secret link than can have an expiration date.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you have 2 workarounds:

- first, you can use [CICP](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/) to create a cloud identity for the user, even with a not Google/gmail/gsuite email address. Then, you can use this email as a Google email
- second, you can build an app, or simply a function which authentified the users and grant it to download file, through the app/function (in fact it's the app/function which have the right on the bucket)